# load balancer redirect to server 1 only for specific urls

Tags: apache, load, server, load-balancing

I have a load balancer that has two servers lets say Server A and Server B. What I want is when i go to siteurl.com/catalog I will be redirected to server A by default and there should be no chance that I will be redirected to Server B. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the best open source load-balancer: HAProxy.
In your backend farm, simply use the 'use-server' directive:

```
backend bk_myapp
  use-server srv1 if { path_beg -i /catalog }
  server srv1 10.0.0.1:80
  server srv2 10.0.0.2:80
```